# Variable height parent (based on first child) with full height second child

Tags: html, css, height

This one's a doozy.

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-left">
        <div class="grandchild">Stuff</div>
        <div class="grandchild">Other stuff</div>
        <div class="grandchild">Stuff</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-right">
        Parent based on expanding height of this element<br/>
        stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>stuff <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/c8s9epea/

I'm trying to get the `.grandchild` elements to expand to 100% of the `.parent` element, which would expand based on the content of `.child-right`. I know if I add a defined height to the parent, the elements will expand correctly, but this isn't ideal.

### How can I have the `.grandchild` elements expand to the height of the `.parent` element in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just change your CSS in the parent and child left to:

```
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.child-left {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Check out the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g69fLnvv/1/).